# Type mismatch exception when using java.math classes on Android

Tags: android

I need to divide 2 BigDecimals in an Android 2.2 application :

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(1);
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(3);
    BigDecimal c = a.divide(b,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

When executing the divide operation I get the following exception :

> Type mismatch Can't assign java.math.RoundingMode to java.math.RoundingMode

I'm using the Android sdk 2.2 platform and the Java sdk 1.6.0.24 in my IDE and the program is deployed on a device running Android 2.2.

Comment: This is quite bizarre.  I just tested it in 2.2 emulator and also on 2.2 device (CM6) - worked fine and `Log.i("test",c.toString())` produced `0.33`.

Comment: Indeed, its quite bizarre. If this was a webapp i would start searching the jars for 2 jars containing the same class (eg one on your app classpath and the other on the servers classpath). But here with Android, i have no clue where to start searching.

Comment: Can you add some debug code to your app?  Do the division in try-catch block; then in the catch part, use reflection to list all loaded classes with name RoundingMode, then use ClassLoader to see where those classes have been loaded from.  You can dump the into the logcat.  You need to do this after the attempted division to ensure that RoundingMode class is loaded.

Comment: I tried it again today and now it works fine. I'll follow your tip when it happens again. tx for yr help.